# How can I insert into a database and if the id I'm provinding already exists it replaces the data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, maui

I'm doing an app with C# in which I wanna have a button so the user can insert lots of data into the database using a .CSV file.
I managed to insert by reading the .CSV file but if I'm trying to insert with an ID that already exists I get an exception and I want it to replace the existent one with the new data.

This is the method that I'm using right now which inserts only if it doesn't already exist

```
private async Task ProcessCsvData(string file)
        {
            string csvData = File.ReadAllText(file);
            string[] rows = csvData.Split('\n');

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            { 
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bool skipFirstIteration = true;

                        foreach(string row in rows)
                        {
                            if(skipFirstIteration)
                            {
                                skipFirstIteration = false;
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                                continue;

                            string[] columns = row.Split(',');

                            string query = "INSERT INTO alumnos(id_alumno, nombre, apellidos, sexo, dni, nie, fecha_nacimiento, " +
                                           "localidad_nacimiento, provincia_nacimiento, nombre_correspondencia, domicilio, localidad, provincia, telefono, " +
                                           "movil, codigo_postal, tutor1, dni_tutor1, tutor2, dni_tutor2, pais, nacionalidad, email_alumno, email_tutor1, " +
                                           "email_tutor2, telefono_tutor1, telefono_tutor2, movil_tutor1, movil_tutor2, apellido1, apellido2, tipo_dom, ntutor1, ntutor2, nss, qr, cod_tarjeta) " +
                                           "VALUES (@id_alumno, @nombre, @apellidos, @sexo, @dni, @nie, @fecha_nacimiento, @localidad_nacimiento, @provincia_nacimiento, " +
                                           "@nombre_correspondencia, @domicilio, @localidad, @provincia, @telefono, @movil, @codigo_postal, @tutor1, @dni_tutor1, @tutor2, " +
                                           "@dni_tutor2, @pais, @nacionalidad, @email_alumno, @email_tutor1, @email_tutor2, @telefono_tutor1, @telefono_tutor2, @movil_tutor1, " +
                                           "@movil_tutor2, @apellido1, @apellido2, @tipo_dom, @ntutor1, @ntutor2, @nss, @qr, @cod_tarjeta)";

                            

                            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                            parameters.Add("@id_alumno", int.Parse(columns[0].Trim()));
                            parameters.Add("@nombre", columns[1].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@apellidos", columns[2].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@sexo", char.Parse(columns[3].Trim()));
                            parameters.Add("@dni", columns[4].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nie", columns[5].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@fecha_nacimiento", DateTime.ParseExact(columns[6].Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                            parameters.Add("@localidad_nacimiento", columns[7].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@provincia_nacimiento", columns[8].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nombre_correspondencia", columns[9].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@domicilio", columns[10].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@localidad", columns[11].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@provincia", columns[12].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@telefono", columns[13].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@movil", columns[14].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@codigo_postal", columns[15].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@tutor1", columns[16].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@dni_tutor1", columns[17].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@tutor2", columns[18].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@dni_tutor2", columns[19].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@pais", columns[20].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nacionalidad", columns[21].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@email_alumno", columns[22].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@email_tutor1", columns[23].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@email_tutor2", columns[24].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@telefono_tutor1", columns[25].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@telefono_tutor2", columns[26].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@movil_tutor1", columns[27].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@movil_tutor2", columns[28].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@apellido1", columns[29].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@apellido2", columns[30].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@tipo_dom", columns[31].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@ntutor1", columns[32].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@ntutor2", columns[33].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nss", columns[34].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@qr", columns[35].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@cod_tarjeta", columns[36].Trim());
                            connection.Execute(query, parameters, transaction);
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error inserting into database: {e.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is what I'm trying to do in order to replace the existent one if it doesn't exist.
I changed the query to MERGE but doesn't seem to work since I get this exception:
"Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll."

```
private async Task ProcessCsvData(string file)
        {
            string csvData = File.ReadAllText(file);
            string[] rows = csvData.Split('\n');

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            { 
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bool skipFirstIteration = true;

                        foreach(string row in rows)
                        {
                            if(skipFirstIteration)
                            {
                                skipFirstIteration = false;
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                                continue;

                            string[] columns = row.Split(',');

                            //string query = @"MERGE INTO alumnos AS target
                            //                 USING (VALUES (@id_alumno, @nombre, @apellidos, @sexo, @dni, @nie, @fecha_nacimiento, 
                            //                                @localidad_nacimiento, @provincia_nacimiento, @nombre_correspondencia, 
                            //                                @domicilio, @localidad, @provincia, @telefono, @movil, @codigo_postal, 
                            //                                @tutor1, @dni_tutor1, @tutor2, @dni_tutor2, @pais, @nacionalidad, 
                            //                                @email_alumno, @email_tutor1, 
                            //                                @email_tutor2, @telefono_tutor1, @telefono_tutor2, @movil_tutor1, @movil_tutor2, 
                            //                                @apellido1, @apellido2, @tipo_dom, @ntutor1, @ntutor2, @nss, @qr, @cod_tarjeta)) 
                            //                        AS source (id_alumno, nombre, apellidos, sexo, dni, nie, fecha_nacimiento, 
                            //                                localidad_nacimiento, provincia_nacimiento, nombre_correspondencia, 
                            //                                domicilio, localidad, provincia, telefono, movil, codigo_postal, 
                            //                                tutor1, dni_tutor1, tutor2, dni_tutor2, pais, nacionalidad, email_alumno, 
                            //                                email_tutor1, email_tutor2, telefono_tutor1, telefono_tutor2, movil_tutor1, movil_tutor2, 
                            //                                apellido1, apellido2, tipo_dom, ntutor1, ntutor2, nss, qr, cod_tarjeta)
                            //                ON target.id_alumno = source.id_alumno
                            //                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                            //                    UPDATE SET target.nombre = source.nombre, 
                            //                               target.apellidos = source.apellidos,
                            //                               target.sexo = source.sexo,
                            //                               target.dni = source.dni,
                            //                               target.nie = source.nie,
                            //                               target.fecha_nacimiento = source.fecha_nacimiento,
                            //                               target.localidad_nacimiento = source.localidad_nacimiento,
                            //                               target.provincia_nacimiento = source.provincia_nacimiento,
                            //                               target.nombre_correspondencia = source.nombre_correspondencia,
                            //                               target.domicilio = source.domicilio,
                            //                               target.localidad = source.localidad,
                            //                               target.provincia = source.provincia,
                            //                               target.telefono = source.telefono,
                            //                               target.movil = source.movil,
                            //                               target.codigo_postal = source.codigo_postal,
                            //                               target.tutor1 = source.tutor1,
                            //                               target.dni_tutor1 = source.dni_tutor1,
                            //                               target.tutor2 = source.tutor2,
                            //                               target.dni_tutor2 = source.dni_tutor2,
                            //                               target.pais = source.pais,
                            //                               target.nacionalidad = source.nacionalidad,
                            //                               target.email_alumno = source.email_alumno,
                            //                               target.email_tutor1 = source.email_tutor1,
                            //                               target.email_tutor2 = source.email_tutor2,
                            //                               target.telefono_tutor1 = source.telefono_tutor1,
                            //                               target.telefono_tutor2 = source.telefono_tutor2,
                            //                               target.movil_tutor1 = source.movil_tutor1,
                            //                               target.movil_tutor2 = source.movil_tutor2,
                            //                               target.apellido1 = source.apellido1,
                            //                               target.apellido2 = source.apellido2,
                            //                               target.tipo_dom = source.tipo_dom,
                            //                               target.ntutor1 = source.ntutor1,
                            //                               target.ntutor2 = source.ntutor2,
                            //                               target.nss = source.nss,
                            //                               target.qr = source.qr,
                            //                               target.cod_tarjeta = source.cod_tarjeta
                            //                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                            //                    INSERT (id_alumno, nombre, apellidos, sexo, dni, nie, fecha_nacimiento, localidad_nacimiento, provincia_nacimiento,
                            //                            nombre_correspondencia, domicilio, localidad, provincia, telefono, movil, codigo_postal, tutor1, dni_tutor1,
                            //                            tutor2, dni_tutor2, pais, nacionalidad, email_alumno, email_tutor1, email_tutor2, telefono_tutor1, 
                            //                            telefono_tutor2, movil_tutor1, movil_tutor2, apellido1, apellido2, tipo_dom, ntutor1, ntutor2, nss, qr, cod_tarjeta)
                            //                    VALUES (@id_alumno, @nombre, @apellidos, @sexo, @dni, @nie, @fecha_nacimiento, @localidad_nacimiento,
                            //                            @provincia_nacimiento, @nombre_correspondencia, @domicilio, @localidad, @provincia, @telefono, @movil,
                            //                            @codigo_postal, @tutor1, @dni_tutor1, @tutor2, @dni_tutor2, @pais, @nacionalidad, @email_alumno,
                            //                            @email_tutor1, @email_tutor2, @telefono_tutor1, @telefono_tutor2, @movil_tutor1, @movil_tutor2,
                            //                            @apellido1, @apellido2, @tipo_dom, @ntutor1, @ntutor2, @nss, @qr, @cod_tarjeta)";

                            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                            parameters.Add("@id_alumno", int.Parse(columns[0].Trim()));
                            parameters.Add("@nombre", columns[1].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@apellidos", columns[2].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@sexo", char.Parse(columns[3].Trim()));
                            parameters.Add("@dni", columns[4].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nie", columns[5].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@fecha_nacimiento", DateTime.ParseExact(columns[6].Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                            parameters.Add("@localidad_nacimiento", columns[7].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@provincia_nacimiento", columns[8].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nombre_correspondencia", columns[9].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@domicilio", columns[10].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@localidad", columns[11].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@provincia", columns[12].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@telefono", columns[13].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@movil", columns[14].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@codigo_postal", columns[15].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@tutor1", columns[16].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@dni_tutor1", columns[17].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@tutor2", columns[18].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@dni_tutor2", columns[19].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@pais", columns[20].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nacionalidad", columns[21].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@email_alumno", columns[22].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@email_tutor1", columns[23].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@email_tutor2", columns[24].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@telefono_tutor1", columns[25].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@telefono_tutor2", columns[26].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@movil_tutor1", columns[27].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@movil_tutor2", columns[28].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@apellido1", columns[29].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@apellido2", columns[30].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@tipo_dom", columns[31].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@ntutor1", columns[32].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@ntutor2", columns[33].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@nss", columns[34].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@qr", columns[35].Trim());
                            parameters.Add("@cod_tarjeta", columns[36].Trim());
                            connection.Execute(query, parameters, transaction);
                        }
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error inserting into database: {e.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried using a REPLACE query instead of the INSERT but I'm using MSSQL and for what I know that doesn't exist.

Any ideas why the query doesn't work?
The connectionString and everything seems to be correct but the query.

Comment: MERGE or check first and then UPDATE... REPLACE is not a sql command  SO it looks like at a quick glance you tried the MERGE; what errors did it have?  I did not review that code....

Comment: UPDATE, INSERT, SELECT and DELETE are fundamental SQL operators you should be familiar with

Comment: If you pull that SQL out and create the values with the parameters and run in SSMS what errors do you see there?

Comment: "Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" what was the actual error message?

Answer (score 0):

your code has performance problem because you connect to DB per Record CSV

Has a lot of way for your problem(First #1 is better way)

#1.

first :import CSV To Temp Table on sql server With C#

then Create A procedure that code procedure  is  merge  final table with Temp Table

#2.

first:Load Data CSV and Send data of CSV to procedure with User-Defined Table Type

then :merge  final table with "input procedure is Table Type" in procedure

#3.

Load Data CSV in Ram and merge with  final table in Memory

#4.Use SSIS

```
create proc MergeCSV
as
//Command Merge
```

UseFullLink:
Passing a List of Values to a Stored Procedure from C#
https://gavilan.blog/2022/04/20/passing-a-list-of-values-to-a-stored-procedure-from-c/

Using MERGE in SQL Server:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/